# JavaFx ImageView giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx

I am having trouble using the `JavaFx ImageView`, it keeps giving me a `NullPointerException` everytime I try accessing it, here is what I did, firstly I set it it up in the  `FXML` like 
`<ImageView fx:id="img_MainScreen" fitHeight="240.0" fitWidth="360.0" pickOnBounds="true"></ImageView>` and in the ControllerClass I added the `FXML` tag and created its object like `@FXML private ImageView img_MainScreen`, after that I go in the `initialize()` and trying printing out its `FitHeight and FitWidth`and trying setting an Image to it because I understand the method is only called after all views have been initialized, so it I do it like

```
public void imageProcessor(ImageView screen)
{
    Thread mainThread = new Thread (new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    try{
                    System.out.println("height of ImageView: "+screen.getFitHeight());
                    System.out.println("Width of ImageView: "+screen.getFitWidth());

                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });mainThread.start();

}


  Jan 20, 2016 11:32:56 AM loginManager.LoginManager showMainView
SEVERE: null
 javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
  /C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xxx/mainWindow.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at loginManager.LoginManager.showMainView(LoginManager.java:184)
at loginManager.LoginManager.authenticated(LoginManager.java:50)
at application.LoginController$1.handle(LoginController.java:67)
at application.LoginController$1.handle(LoginController.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 58 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.MainViewController.initialize(MainViewController.java:73)
... 67 more
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace, and indicate which line causes the Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Why are you using a separate thread? This can add all kinds of concurrency issues, especially when methods from JavaFX objects are not called on the JavaFX application thread. In any case, try posting an [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AndreasFester even without a seperate thread its failing

Comment: I have added the error

Comment: @AndreasFester and I removed the thread nothing changed

Comment: The exception is not occurring in the code you posted; it is occurring in the `initialize()` method, at line 73. Please post the code for that method an indicate which line is line 73.

Comment: yes at line 73 in initialize method where am calling the method processvideo, its occuring at the method call

Comment: Can you post that code (the code that is on line 73, at least, but preferably the whole `initialize()` method)? The exception is thrown by the code you execute at line 73 (not by some code in the method you call from line 73).

Comment: Although you said that the variable name is `img_MainScreen`, in `initilialize()` method you are accessing to `screen.getFitHeight()` where `screen` is probably is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your fxml can't be loaded.

```
  Jan 20, 2016 11:32:56 AM loginManager.LoginManager showMainView
SEVERE: null
 javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
  /C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xxx/mainWindow.fxml
```

Unless you provide the full code, especially how you load it, nobody can help you.

Comment: i fixed it, it was been caused by the calling of a method from another class i do not know how an imageview is connect to that but putting the function in the same class solved it